# how to use rbenv to manage local gems

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I've been using Middleman since a while, but very recently it is getting some issues in loading. 
This is likely due to the coexistence of very old gems of the same type.

Have to say that I did follow some online suggestions, but haven't really got the full understanding. So ended up using rbenv for managing ruby then bundle to install the gems.

Now, have two project that for which I need to "reset" and install only the referenced gems into the local folder or somehow they don't conflict.
I can't figure out how to do it.

Using the rbenv -local I can change the local ruby version, but not sure how to move next.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need rbenv or rvm for this, although their are good tools. To run a piece of code with just the gems you need, and the versions you specified in your Gemfile, run any command prefixed with `bundle exec`.

For example `bundle exec middleman server`.

Comment: Well that's how they are setup. But somehow now my project stopped working. I tried to initialiase a new folder with middleman and it says that a previous version of the blog gem conflicts with the recent one.

Comment: @AndreaMoro If you get such an error then the problem is there and not with rbenv. You should post the full error message in the question, or make a new question pertaining to middleman.

Comment: @Casper in fact I was after understanding how to create a real separated environment using rbenv ... which will conversely help to fix this.